# Change materialized view to on commit

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I have a materialized view I would like to alter to on commit (from on demand) using fast refresh.

However I constantly get

```
ora-32337 cannot alter materialized view with pending changes refresh on commit
```

even directly after a refresh (and knowing that no change was done).

What could be the cause for this? The MV uses outer joins, could that be an issue? (MV log is available for all tables)

Comment: Can you just drop the materialized view and recreate it as refresh on commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @eaolson said you should just drop the materialized view and recreate it as refresh on commit. This the only way..

Comment: Be careful with just dropping the Materialized View. Remember to check for constraints on the materialized view/table otherwise you might break things without knowing. The safer choice is to perform a manual refresh and then change to refresh on commit. 
`DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('Owner.MViewName','C');
ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW Owner.MViewName REFRESH ON COMMIT;`

Answer (score 0):

As bedeem said, perform a manual refresh then then alter it to refresh on commit.

```
DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('Owner.MViewName','C');
ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW Owner.MViewName REFRESH ON COMMIT;
```